# Add array name in beginning using PHP multidimensional arrays to convert MySQL to JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, multidimensional-array

I want the array name institution to be displayed at the beginning.
My JSON Code currently displays the the following format.

```
{
    "institution": [],
    "id": "2",
    "name": "kjhl kjhl",
    "updated_date": "2017-11-12 21:43:13",
    "description": [{
        "id": "3",
        "description": "h,nm.,"
    }]
}
```

I want JSON code to be displayed the following format.

```
{"institution":[{
    "id": "2", 
    "name": "kjhl kjhl", 
    "updated_date": "2017-11-12 21:43:13", 
    "description": [{ 
        "id": "3", 
        "description": "h,nm.," 
    }] 
}]}
```

Here is my code.

```
<?php
include_once "db.php";

$usersList_array =array();
$user_array = array();
$note_array = array();
  if(isset($_POST['updated_date'])) {

$fetch_users = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE updated_date > timestamp('".$_POST["updated_date"]."')  ORDER BY id desc" );


 $user_array['institution'] = array();
while ($row_users = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch_users)) {

    $user_array['id'] = $row_users['id'];
    $user_array['name'] = $row_users['name'].' '.$row_users['name'];
    $user_array['updated_date']=$row_users["updated_date"];
    $user_array['description'] = array();

    $fetch_notes = mysql_query("SELECT t2.id, t2.description FROM test2 t2 ,test1 t1 where t1.id=t2.oid and oid = ".$row_users['id']."");
    while ($row_notes = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch_notes)) {
        $note_array['id']=$row_notes['id'];
        $note_array['description']=$row_notes['description'];
        array_push($user_array['description'],$note_array);

    }
          array_push($usersList_array,$user_array);
}

$jsonData = json_encode($usersList_array, 128);
echo $jsonData; 

?>
```

What do I need to change? Where is my error?

Comment: what if your institution array in input has some values already?

Comment: first of all `mysql` is now deprecated so don't use it anymore

Comment: institution array should contain id,name,updated_date has well as description which is multidimensional array

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all! Prepared Statements can be used if you use any of the _non deprecated/removed_ API's: `Mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: Also, your 1st query is pointless because you overwrite the resultset with the next query. You seem to be missing an else branch. You also seem to use php loops instead of joins at certain places.

Comment: keep key in the array like, `array_push($usersList_array['institution'],$user_array);`
hope it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved your problem.work fine now
at first i simulated your code.this is with my values.

```
<?php

$usersList_array =array();
$user_array = array();
$note_array = array();

$user_array1['institution'] = array();

$user_array['id'] = "1";
$user_array['name'] = "mori";
$user_array['updated_date']="2017";

$user_array['description'] = array();

$note_array['id']="2";
$note_array['description']="descriptiondescription";

array_push($user_array['description'],$note_array);
array_push($user_array1['institution'],$user_array);
//$user_array1['institution'] =array($user_array);
//array_push($usersList_array,$user_array1);

 $jsonData = json_encode($user_array1, 128);
echo $jsonData; 
?>
```

And it is your code

```
<?php
include_once "db.php";

$usersList_array =array();
$user_array = array();
$note_array = array();
  if(isset($_POST['updated_date'])) {

$fetch_users = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE updated_date > timestamp('".$_POST["updated_date"]."')  ORDER BY id desc" );


 $user_array1['institution'] = array();
while ($row_users = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch_users)) {

    $user_array['id'] = $row_users['id'];
    $user_array['name'] = $row_users['name'].' '.$row_users['name'];
    $user_array['updated_date']=$row_users["updated_date"];
    $user_array['description'] = array();

    $fetch_notes = mysql_query("SELECT t2.id, t2.description FROM test2 t2 ,test1 t1 where t1.id=t2.oid and oid = ".$row_users['id']."");
    while ($row_notes = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch_notes)) {
        $note_array['id']=$row_notes['id'];
        $note_array['description']=$row_notes['description'];
      //  array_push($user_array['description'],$note_array);
        array_push($user_array['description'],$note_array);

    }
          array_push($user_array1['institution'],$user_array);
         // array_push($usersList_array,$user_array1);

         // array_push($usersList_array,$user_array);
}

$jsonData = json_encode($usersList_array, 128);
echo $jsonData; 

?>
```